# unable to start fedora service from ubuntu

Tags: webapps

when i tries to start my fedora service using the command " idris@idris-OptiPlex-780:~$ service fedora start" 
it says that:couldn't read file "database": no such file or directory
/etc/inti.d/fedora: 15: .: Can't open /etc/RC.d/inti.d/functions

please help me how to solve, i will be very happy if it fixes

thank you